# Test for presence/absence of hidden field with jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, hidden-field

```jsx
<div className="errorMsg" hidden={props.error === true ? false : true}>
  Error message text
</div>
```

I have this div that is hidden if `props.Error` is false, and displayed if it's true. I am trying to test that the text does/doesn't appear depending on prop value. Since I'm using shallow render, the test `expect(wrapper.find('.errorMsg').length).toEqual(1);` is always going to pass whether hidden is true or not. I'm using shallow render because that's necessary for my other tests, and so far I've tried:

```jsx
expect(wrapper.find('.garmentOriginErrorMsg').length).toEqual(0);
expect(wrapper.find('.errorMsg')).toHaveProperty('props', 'hidden: true')
expect(wrapper.find('.errorMsg').displayed()).toBeFalsy()
expect(wrapper.find('.errorMsg').hasStyle('display', 'none')).toBe(true)
```

Is this possible with shallow rendering, or is my only option to use mount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work with `shallow`:

```
expect(wrapper.find('.errorMsg').props().hidden).toBe(true);
```

Also, `props.error === true ? false : true` can be written simply as `!props.error`

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly. Appreciate the answer.